# Solution for transnational email from any domain

Tags: email, smtp

We have a small CRM that suppose to serve 10-20 customers.
Each customer needs his CRM to send auto emails (100 per day).
Some of our customers doe's even have a domain, they are using gmail / yahoo or maybe very very small and unknown email provider.

I need an SMTP solution that will allow me to send email in the name of the user, meaning that the `from` address will be for example `my.email@gmail.com` or `my.email@someotherhost.com` so the client can reply and get directly to their inbox.
I know that in SMTP protocol I can use whatever `from` address you want. but I assume that it would not be succeeded to enter the inbox.

Do you know such service?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To avoid hitting spam triggers and issues with things like SPF the easiest thing to do is set the from to be a no-reply@ generic type thing and set the reply-to to be the email you want used when someone hits the "reply" or "reply all" button in their mail client.  This of course would all be done when the headers are created for the email (however your system does that)

As to a server solution, I'd look at a linode.com account, a 'node with Debian Jessie on it, with postfix+mysql+dovecot all set up for virtual domains and users with management via simple php forms or just raw sql statements.  While not perfect, this - https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie is a good configuration guide.